# How to make change to /etc/profile instantly effective inside script

Tags: bash, command-line

In my bash script, I changed something to my `/etc/profile` and I do `source /etc/profile`, but after the script finished, the change isn't effective instantly. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo echo "BLAHBLAH_HOME=/opt/BLAHBLAH" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile
echo $BLAHBLAH_HOME
```

According to output, the change is made during the script's running time, but if I run `echo $BLAHBLAH_HOME` after, the change isn't effective, I have to `source /etc/profile` again. So, how to make the change effective even after running the script?

Answer (score 0):

You source the profile WITHIN the script, so the environment of the process running the script is changed, not yours outside the script... until you source it yourself outside the script.

Comment: so, they are totally separate spaces, and can not effect each other? I have to source it again outside to make it effective globally?

Comment: Correct. When you start the script, a new, independent process is created and bash runs in that environment and any changes you make to the environment variables within there are local to that process and die when it exits. However, in the script you also change an item in the permanent filesystem (namely `/etc/profile`), and if you want the shell that you are currently typing into to see that change, you must tell it to look at `/etc/profile` - by sourcing it into your current shell (not the one you started in the script).

Comment: They are correct.  In fact, if you run your script by "source yourscript.sh", it should be working.